# Append Changed and New Employees to Existing Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Table 1) which is a list of employees and data points about them. The data that populated Table 1 is regularly changed and added to in its source system and then is loaded into another table (Table 2) via a CSV.

If data changes for a certain employee, I want to update one column in that employees record in Table 1 to mark that it has since changed and then add a new row to the table with that employees changed data along with any new employees from Table 2 that didn't already exist in Table 1.

Example:

Table1:

```
Status |  ID  |  Name  |  Department  | Title 
    
Active   767    John       Tech         Analyst
Active   789    Alex       Tech         Courier
```

Table2:

```
Status |  ID  |  Name  |  Department  | Title 
    
Active   767    John       Tech         Director -- the title changed for this employee
Active   789    Alex       Tech         Courier
```

Desired Output of Table1:

```
Status |  ID  |  Name  |  Department  | Title 
        
Active   767    John       Tech         Director  -- Updated Employee data from Table2
Changed  767    John       Tech         Analyst   -- Old Employee Data from Table1
Active   789    Alex       Tech         Courier
```

With the query below, I am attempting to update Table1 via an outer join which in theory should append any rows that do not meet the where criteria to the table as a separate row and join on all rows that do meet it. However, the employees with changed data are not being added to the table, only the status is being updated. I want to add employees who have changed their any of their departments, titles, etc. and any new employees that don't already exist in Table1

How can I ensure employees whose data have changed are added as new rows while joining employees that have not.

Query:

```
UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[CBC_legacy] 
SET
       [Position Status] =[CBC].[Position Status] 
      ,[Employee ID] = [CBC].[Employee ID] 
      ,[Full Legal Name] = [CBC].[Full Legal Name]
      ,[Hire/Rehire Date] = [CBC].[Hire/Rehire Date]
      ,[Annual Salary] = [CBC].[Annual Salary]
      ,[Job Title] = [CBC].[Job Title]
      ,[Kamsa Job Code] = [CBC].[Kamsa Job Code]
      ,[Home Department] = [CBC].[Home Department]
      ,[Worked In Country] = [CBC].[Worked In Country]
      ,[Budget ID] = [CBC].[Budget ID]
      ,[Work Location] = [CBC].[Work Location]
      ,[Regular Pay Currency] = [CBC].[Regular Pay Currency]

FROM [Database].[dbo].[CBC_legacy] AS CBCL
FULL OUTER JOIN [Database].[dbo].[CBC_data] CBC
ON CBCL.[Employee ID] = CBC.[Employee ID] 
WHERE [CBC].[Employee ID] = [CBCL].[Employee ID] 
                AND [CBC].[Job Title] = [CBCL].[Job Title] 
                AND [CBC].[Home Department] = [CBCL].[Home Department] 
                AND [CBC].[Annual Salary] = [CBCL].[Annual Salary]

SELECT * FROM [Database].[dbo].[CBC_legacy] ORDER BY [Full Legal Name]
```

Comment: Update does not append, Insert does. You need to insert all the new details, and update any existing if their status has changed. Start by building queries which produce the results you want, then convert them to an insert and update.

Comment: You're the one who suggested this

Comment: Not at all, I suggested exactly what I said in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 queries, one for the update and one for the insert.
I assume that only Department and Title can change in this example, if more columns can change than just add them to the where clause

```
-- update status
update t1
set    t1.Status = 'Changed'
from   table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where  (t2.Department <> t1.Department
        or
        t2.Title <> t1.Title
       )

-- insert new row from table2
insert into table1
select t2.Status, t2.Id, t2.Name, t2.Department, t2.Title
from   table2 t2
  left join table1 t1 on t2.id = t1.id
                      and ( t2.Department <> t1.Department
                            or
                            t2.Title <> t1.Title
                          )  
where not exists ( select 1
                   from   table1 t1
                   where  t1.id = t2.id
                   and    t1.status = t2.status
                   and    t1.name = t2.name
                   and    t1.department = t2.department
                 )
group by t2.Status, t2.Id, t2.Name, t2.Department, t2.Title  

select * from table1 order by id, status
```

Click on [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e962009090056bf9039540827c2401c5) to see it working

The result is

| Status | id | name | department | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Active | 767 | John | Tech | Director |
| Changed | 767 | John | Tech | Analist |
| Active | 787 | Alex | Tech | Courier |
| Active | 800 | Picard | Tech | Captain |

**EDIT changes as requested in the comments**

When someone changes more then once, the original query inserted his new position more than once. This can be solved by grouping the changes.

See this [Updated DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=672638b3ba4bed4d7debc525fed7c9c7)

Comment: Thanks this gets close but two issues: 1. It doesnt add new employees from Table2 to Table1 because of the Inner Join and 2. It keeps adding John over and over again everytime I run the query, it should only add him once

Comment: @user4636353 I changed my answer so that issue 2 is fixed, give me some time for issue 1

Comment: @user4636353 Issue 1 is now also fixed

Comment: This worked and solved my problem so I have marked it as the solution. However, I did notice if "John" Changes for a third time, it will duplicate the new third record and so on, is there a way to avoid duplicates if they change more than twice? This may be beyond the scope of the question an I can post another one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user4636353 I made an edit to my answer to address this problem, see the DBFiddle in the edit

Comment: You are an artist, thanks much!